# call function inside argument of a function in python

Tags: python

I am starting with python, and I am trying to understand the sample code that Phidget website give to me (I bought a Phidget Bridge 4 input where I have plug on 4 gauge cell). For my project I need to use python but not much use to it.

To read only one channel, sol only one gauge cell with my Phidget bridge, the website give me this code.

```
from Phidget22.Phidget import *
from Phidget22.Devices.VoltageRatioInput import *
import time

def onVoltageRatioChange(self, voltageRatio):
    print("VoltageRatio: " + str(voltageRatio))

def main():
    voltageRatioInput0 = VoltageRatioInput()

    voltageRatioInput0.setOnVoltageRatioChangeHandler(onVoltageRatioChange)

    voltageRatioInput0.openWaitForAttachment(5000)

    time.sleep(5)

    voltageRatioInput0.close()

main()
```

There is the function `def onVoltageRatioChange(self, voltageRatio):` which takes 2 arguments, self and voltageRatio, and this function is used inside `setOnVoltageRatioChangeHandler(onVoltageRatioChange)` with no argument. What I mean, it's that I do not get why we give as an argument `onVoltageChange` (which is normally a function) to the function `setOnVoltageRatioChangeHandler`...

It someone could explain it to me, it could help me to build my own code... at least try.. 
thank you

Comment: Don't call us. We'll call you. (As soon as the voltage ratio changes, we'll call the function you gave us.)

Comment: `setOnVoltageRatioChangeHandler` give args to `onVoltageRatioChange` inside ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Phidget22` knows how to detect a voltage ratio change, but it doesn't know what you want to do with it: maybe you want to sound an alarm. maybe you want to send an email with the new ratio. maybe you just want to print it to the screen.

So it uses `setOnVoltageRatioChangeHandler` to ask you what you would like to do once it detects this voltage change, saying "hey, if you'll give me a function that takes a voltage ratio, I'll call it when I detect a change" then you can do:

```
setOnVoltageRatioChangeHandler(soundTheAlarm)
```

or

```
setOnVoltageRatioChangeHandler(sendAnEmail)
```

or:

```
setOnVoltageRatioChangeHandler(printToScreen)
```

The supplied `onVoltageRatioChange` will just print the new value to the screen.

Generally, passing a function as an argument is a great way to give flexibility in the way events are handled. It's basically saying "I know how to detect a certain situation or get a certain value. You let me know what you want me to do once I do"

Comment: Thank you for this answer !

Comment: But nVoltageRatioChange normally need some arguments, we do not give it directly ? maybe setOnVoltageRatioChangeHandler is giving the 2 arguments we need (self and voltageRatio) ? @shayelk

Comment: `setOnVoltageRatioChangeHandler` is a setter. It will store the function you gave it for later use. Then, when a voltage ratio change will be detected, your function (`onVoltageRatioChange`) will be called with the new ratio as an argument (note that `onVoltageRatioChange` actually takes one argument. the `self` argument is the object it belongs to, but that's a story for a different question ;) )